# Start app as root with pm2

Tags: node.js, root, pm2

I have a daemon that must be run as root on startup.

I use pm2 to start other apps but can not figure out if it can start an app as root. Can it be done?

If not, what are my options?

Answer (score 43):

I had problems with `sudo pm2 start api`, but this was since pm2 was already running without sudo privileges, therefor you need to run:

```
pm2 kill
sudo pm2 start api
```

This kills the pm2 deamon first, so that it starts in sudo, but then you need sudo for **ALL** pm2 commands afterwards, like: `sudo pm2 ls`

Comment: Perfect! I had pm2 running as ubuntu user, once I ran these commands my instance of pm2 is now running as root as needed to run https on my node server using port 3000.

Answer (score 28):

If you only need your daemon to be run as root in order to access a port number (such as 80 or 443), the [pm2 documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#allow-pm2-to-bind-applications-on-ports-80-443-without-root) recommends using `authbind`.  So, if you want the user `yourusername` to have access to port 80, run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install authbind
$ sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
$ sudo chown yourusername /etc/authbind/byport/80
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/authbind/byport/80
$ authbind --deep pm2 update
```

And then use `authbind --deep pm2` instead of `pm2`.  The documentation suggests setting up an alias.

Comment: are you assuming linux?

Comment: Yes, and `apt-get` is only available on distributions based on Debian.

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend:

```
sudo pm2 start index.js
```

OR

```
pm2 start 'http-server' /var/www -p 80
sudo pm2 startup
pm2 save
```

OR

```
pm2 start 'which http-server' /var/www -p 80
```

To start it on your HTTP Port

Also, I always put `-i 0` at the end  -  this starts up as many worker processes as you have cores. Check [THIS](https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/)

It is not always necessary to start PM2 as root. If you have PM2 as root and the cli module installed, security is a big risk. This is only required if you're starting your app on a port between 1 and 1024

Answer (score 7):

Wasted about an hour

On AWS EC2 machine, one system was in inconsistent state due to earlier installations, that forced `sudo` elevations in the application for all commands to OS, like sh, etc.

pm2 **was** running as root:

```
ps aux | grep pm2
# root ... PM2 v4.1.2: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)
```

Now pm2 **is** running as ubuntu:

```
ps aux | grep pm2
# ubuntu  ...  PM2 v4.1.2: God Daemon (/home/ubuntu/.pm2)
```

Below commands worked:

```
sudo pm2 kill
sudo npm remove pm2 -g

sudo npm i -g pm2@latest
sudo pm2 update
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.pm2
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should start pm2 as a root, (sudo pm2 start app.js), then your app will start as a root

Comment: This does work but it seems to require that I run the other apps as root aswell.

Answer (score 0):

First, install pm2 globally.
Then set  root permissions to pm2 using  this  command

```
sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.pm2/rpc.sock /home/ubuntu/.pm2/pub.sock
```

Comment: Why are you passing in `ubuntu:ubuntu`? In a different distribution would it be `root:user_to_give_root_access`?

Comment: I used an ec2 instance in aws and I logged as ubuntu user, for a root user your answer will work. I just gave an example of how it works. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

you might consider routing your traffic with iptables, since there is a reason behind this errror

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```