# How to serve node.js app which calls a C program requiring root access for /dev/mem?

Tags: c, node.js, server, pm2

I have a node.js app ([dhildreth/bhs-api](https://bitbucket.org/dhildreth/bhs-api)) running on a [single board computer](https://www.embeddedarm.com/products/TS-7680) that makes a system call to a [C program](https://bitbucket.org/dhildreth/bhs-api/src/a0ba9d7c897c9a21858af411f3aecf5c1e10068a/src/getadc/getadc.c?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) which requires reading */dev/mem* to read voltage from an ADC pin.  During development, I've been running everything as root or sudo.  For example:

```
sudo node server.js
```

I'm now ready to move to production, so I need to have the node server run on startup.  I'm familiar with pm2, so I was going to set that up to [run as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105100/start-app-as-root-with-pm2).  However, I'm curious about best practices in this case.  Does my app, with its need for access to */dev/mem*, require me to do so?  Is there something else I should consider?  For example, setting permissions on */dev/mem* for non-root access (if there is such a thing)?

This is what I was going to do before I wondered if there was a different way and what the best practices are:

```
sudo pm2 start server.js --name bhs-api
sudo pm2 startup
sudo pm2 save
```

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: It would probably reduce your security exposure to make the C program SUID-root, and to run the Node app as a non-root user.

Comment: Thanks much, John.  What does making the C program SUID-root entail?  Is it simply adding the line setuid(0); to main()?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the `setuid()` function, nor is it in fact part of the program's implementation at all.  It means making root the owner of the binary, and turning on the SUID bit in its mode (permissions).  Something like `chown root:root my_binary; chmod 4755 my_binary`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  Will give it a go.

Comment: John, that worked!  Thank you.